# How to look inside the notification of didChangeScreenParametersNotification in swift?

Tags: swift, macos

This is my code, I am getting notification once I change the dock size, but I want to look inside the notification for reading the updated values, here is my code:

```
        var myNotificationObserver: NSObjectProtocol? = nil
        
        myNotificationObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification, object: NSApplication.shared, queue: .main) { [weak self] newNotification in
            
            if let notification = newNotification.object as? NSScreen {
                print(notification.visibleFrame.size)
            }
            
        }
```

I am casting the notification as `NSScreen` in my codes which doesn't work, I don't know what is the correct type for casting it in order to use the information of notification.

Comment: According to the documentation: "The notification object is `sharedApplication`. This notification doesn’t contain a userInfo dictionary.". There is no other information in the notification.